# Accessing controls of views of NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, nscollectionview

I'm using an `NSCollectionView` to display various objects. The whole things works rather well, except for one annoying thing. I cannot figure out how to access the various controls on the view used to represent each object in the collection.

Here's the setup:

- I have dragged an `NSCollectionView` into my view in IB.
- I made a custom subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem`. Mapped my class in IB.
- I made a custom subclass of `NSBox` to act as the view for each object in the collection. Also mapped this class in IB and connected it to the `view` property of my `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass.
- I made all the bindings in IB to display the correct information for each object.

The view:

[image]

The resulting collection view:

[image]

Reasoning that that my subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem` is basically a controller for each view in the collection, I made referencing outlets of the various controls in the view in my controller subclass:

```
@interface SourceCollectionViewItem : NSCollectionViewItem

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *nameTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *typeTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet RSLabelView *labelView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *viewButton;

@end
```

When I inspect any instance of `SourceCollectionViewItem` in the debugger, all the properties show up as nil despite the fact that I can actually see them on my screen and that everything is displayed as it should be.

My setup was inspired by Apple's sample app [IconCollection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html).

I am obviously missing something. What?

EDIT: I found various posts hinting at a similar issue:
[CocoaBuilder.com](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/278409-how-do-bind-custom-view-properties-to-an-nscollectionviewitem.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194395/how-do-you-initialize-a-nscollectionviewitem) on SO.

EDIT: Just to be complete: [this post](http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/72) deals with the subject as well and delivers a solution based on a combination of the options mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: The link in the second EDIT is broken. But I found the blog post through the [WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120124050817/http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/72)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outlets are set during nib loading, and only the prototype item is loaded from nib and has its outlets assigned. All other `ViewItem`s and their `View`s are cloned from the prototype, in that case outlets are just instance variables that are never initialized.

Here are the options I could come up with:

- Override `newItemForRepresentedObject:` of collection view and reload nib instead of cloning the prototype. But this will probably hurt the performance greatly.
- Override `copyWithZone` of collection view item and assign outlets manually using  `viewWithTag:` to find them.
- Give up and try to provide data via bindings only.

Answer (score 1):

I found that overriding NSCollectionViewItem's `-setRepresentedObject:` could also be a good choice, as it is called on the new Item when all IBOutlet seem to be ready. After the call to `super` you can do whatever is needed:

```
- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    if (representedObject) {
        [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
        [self.anOutlet bind:@"property" toObject:self.representedObject withKeyPath:@"representeProperty" options:nil];
    }
}
```

I used this method to bind a custom property of an interface object. The check is there to avoid useless calls, when the representedObject is not yet ready. The project uses a separate xib for the ViewItem, as explained in the links in the original edits.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. Like @hamstergene suggests, you can use `copyWithZone`, it will be much more efficient compared to `newItemForRepresentedObject`. However `viewWithTag` is not always an option, first, because not everything can be tagged (easily), and, second, using tag for this purpose is a little wrong. Here's a cool approach with performance in mind, in Swift.

```
import AppKit

class MyViewController: NSCollectionItemView
{

    // Here you are cloning the original item loaded from the storyboard, which has 
    // outlets available, but as you've seen the default implementation doesn't take
    // care of them. Each view has a unique identifiers, which you can use to find it
    // in sublayers. What's really cool about this, is that you don't need to assign
    // any tags or do anything else while having advantage of better performance using
    // cached nib object.

    override func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        let copy: NSCollectionItemView = super.copyWithZone(zone) as! NSCollectionItemView
        let oldView: RecordingView = self.view as! MyView
        let newView: RecordingView = copy.view as! MyView

        newView.foo = newView.viewWithIdentifier(oldView.foo.identifier!) as! NSTextfield
        newView.bar = newView.viewWithIdentifier(oldView.bar.identifier!) as! NSImageView

        return copy
    }
}

@IBDesignable class MyView: View
{

    // Custom collection view item view. Lets assume inside of it you have two subviews which you want
    // to access in your code.

    @IBOutlet weak var foo: NSTextfield!
    @IBOutlet weak var bar: NSImageView!
}

extension NSView
{

    // Similar to viewWithTag, finds views with the given identifier.

    func viewWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> NSView? {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview.identifier == identifier {
                return subview
            } else if subview.subviews.count > 0, let subview: NSView = subview.viewWithIdentifier(identifier) {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```